# Rails how to call helpers such as .humanize on an attribute of collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this collection_select `<%= collection_select(:template, :template_id, @templates, :id, :name) %>` and I want to basically call `:name.humanize`, but obviously that doesn't work.

How can i call a method such as `.humanize` on an attribute of collection_select (a hash attribute?)

**EDIT**

Here's a snippet from my controller:

```
@templates = Template.select(:name).group(:name)
p "templates = #{@templates}"
```

Here's what appears in the console:

```
"templates = #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f84451b7af8>"
```

Comment: I would do this when building the @templates object.

Comment: Yeah, agree with @Candide, I probably will have another attribute of help do this kind of thing.

Comment: Can either of you elaborate? Maybe with some code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**With Rails 4**

Just like this:

`<%= collection_select(:template, :template_id, @templates, :id, Proc.new {|v| v.name.humanize}) %>`

In the `Proc` block, `v` will be your models, iterated through a `each` loop.

`collection_select` works with anything that inherit from `Enumerable` and have no limit in the content of the Proc.

**With Rails 3**

You must do it your self, by preparing your data before passing it to `collection_select`

```
# This will generate an Array of Arrays
values = @templates.map{|t| [t.id, t.name.humanize]}
# [ [record1.id, record1.name.humanize], [record2.id, record2.name.humanize], ... ]

# This will use the Array previously generated, and loop in it:
#   - send :first to get the value (it is the first item of each Array inside the Array)
#   - send :last to get the text (it is the last item of each Array inside the Array)
#     ( we could have use :second also )
<%= collection_select(:template, :template_id, values, :first, :last) %>
```

Comment: Where does the variable `v` come from though? I tried this as you have it and it gives me an error `#<Proc:0x007f8445666220@/Users/tomcaflisch/Sites/myproject/app/views/applications/edit.html.erb:56> is not a symbol`

Comment: Sorry for being so dense, but are you saying that the Proc's `v` value comes from my `@templates` variable? I've edited my question with more info because i'm still receiving the error in my previous comment.

Comment: No problem, let's troubleshoot this. Can you please: 1) try in your rails console the 2 examples of my answer, just to confirm a simple case would work. 2) instead of `Template.select(:name).group(:name)` try `Template.all` and see if it works. I'll be waiting for your results. Thanks

Comment: I tried your first exmaple and here's the output: `irb(main):004:0> collection_select :object, :method, values, :last, proc
TypeError: #<Proc:0x007fa6b0be7cc0@(irb):3> is not a symbol`. I also tried the change to `Template.all` and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Ok my bad, I just tried with a Rails 3 console and it's indeed not possible, I edited my answer to include the Rails 3 way

Comment: Ok that seems to work, but can you explain what `:first` and `:last` are? In my question I have the 4th and 5th params as `:id`, and `:name`. Now that i used `@templates.map` as you suggested, i removed params 4 and 5 and it still works great. Do i need `:first` and `:last`?

Comment: Those are the methods 'sent' to each element of your collection. Have a look at the source of `extract_values_from_collection` to understand how it works, it's in your 'rails' gem, in file actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb

Comment: That's it edited, you got all information you need now :) don't hesitate to read rails internal code, it is very instructive